# BERT text classification with K fold cross validation returns "Target 3 is out of bounds" error

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, text-classification, bert-language-model

I am working on training a dataset of sentences to be grouped into one of three categories. I am trying to do this based off of code found in this very helpful medium article (https://medium.com/swlh/k-fold-as-cross-validation-with-a-bert-text-classification-example-4017f76a863a). My code is almost identical:

```
n=5
kf = KFold(n_splits=n, shuffle=True)

results = []

for train_index, val_index in kf.split(data):
  # splitting Dataframe (dataset not included)
    train_df = data.iloc[train_index]
    val_df = data.iloc[val_index]
    # Defining Model
    model = ClassificationModel('bert', 'bert-base-uncased', use_cuda=False) 
  # train the model
    model.train_model(train_df)
  # validate the model 
    result, model_outputs, wrong_predictions = model.eval_model(val_df, acc=accuracy_score)
    print(result['acc'])
  # append model score
    results.append(result['acc'])
```

At line " model.train_model(train_df)", I keep getting an index error `"IndexError: Target 3 is out of bounds."`

Could someone please help me understand why that is and how I can address it?

Comment: Could you please show the stack trace too, so it is clear that the error comes from the loss function?

Comment: Yes this is the complete error I got:
```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-e3cb3d52a227> in <module>()
     23 )  
     24   # train the model
---> 25     model.train_model(train_df)
     26   # validate the model
     27     result, model_outputs, wrong_predictions = model.eval_model(val_df, acc=accuracy_score)
'''
(1/2)

Comment: ```
7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in nll_loss(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction)
   2216                          .format(input.size(0), target.size(0)))
   2217     if dim == 2:
-> 2218         ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
   2219     elif dim == 4:
   2220         ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss2d(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)

IndexError: Target 3 is out of bounds.

(2/2)

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify the number of target classes in the model constructor, so it defaults to whatever is in the default config file (see [the code where it happens](https://github.com/ThilinaRajapakse/simpletransformers/blob/38d0cd838f24a94ce27aa30fd180dab815d64889/simpletransformers/classification/classification_model.py#L179)). When number `3` occurs among the target classes, it is suddenly out of range of the prediction.

Use the `num_labels` argument in the constructor (see [the documentation](https://simpletransformers.ai/docs/classification-models/#class-classificationmodel)).